# Cant complete a complex query in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have this two tables:

```py
class HotelInfo(models.Model):
    country_area = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    hotel_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    hotel_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hotel_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hotel_address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    review_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    review_qty = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    clean = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    comf = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    loct = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    fclt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    staff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    vfm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    wifi = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'hotel_info'
        unique_together = (('hotel_id', 'country_area'),)
        verbose_name_plural = "hotels"


class HotelReviews(models.Model):
    uuid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column='UUID', max_length=36, blank=True)
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(HotelInfo, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    review_title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    review_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    review_score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    review_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    reviewer_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hash_reviewer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    reviewer_location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    posting_conts = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    positive_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    negative_content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n1 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n2 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n3 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n4 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    tag_n5 = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    staydate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'hotel_reviews'
        verbose_name_plural = "Reviews"
```

This is my serializer file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import HotelInfo
from .models import HotelReviews


class HotelInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelInfo
        fields = '__all__'


class HotelReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = HotelReviews
        fields = '__all__'
```

And I want get the hotels with more than 5 reviews_qty in 2019 and then get the reviews between 2 dates, this is what I have for the moment:

```py
queryset = HotelReviews.objects.filter(review_date__range=('2018-01-01', '2019-12-12')).filter(hotel__review_qty__gte=5).select_related('hotel')
```

I guess i need use active_not_deleted but dont know how to get only the hotels that have more than 5 reviews in 2019.

Comment: if you want greater than 5 use `__gt=5` in place of `__lte=5`

Comment: yes I know thats a mistake because when I use ```__gte=5``` the data retrieved its too big and the server crashes...that was just for testing results. I fix it know on the question...but this dont help to get the final query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you aren't going to be able to use the field `review_qty` if that field doesn't take into account when the reviews were posted (that is just an integer and can't know about dates).  So you're going to need to annotate your hotel with the quantity of reviews for that year.  Something like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
hotel_with_2019_reviews = HotelReviews.objects.filter(
   review_date__range=('2019-01-01', '2019-12-31')
).values('hotel').annotate(
   review_qty=Count('id')
).filter(review_qty__gte=5)
```

Comment: I do what you do like this:


```queryset = HotelReviews.objects.annotate(reviews_2019_qty=Count('hotel', filter=Q(review_date__range=('2019-01-01', '2019-12-12')))).filter(reviews_2019_qty__gte=5)```




Now i have this error:



```(1055, "Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Hiring_task.hotel_reviews.hotel_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")```

This is more than i know of bbdd... Im just a student

Comment: you've flipped what I wrote - I said take the Hotel and annotate it by count of reviews.  You're taking the Reviews and annotating them by count of Hotel, which is backwards.

Comment: but like this i cant get access to review_data...now i have this:


```queryset = HotelInfo.objects.annotate(reviews_2019_qty=Count('hotelreviews', filter=Q(review_date__range=('2019-01-01', '2019-12-12')))).filter(reviews_2019_qty__gte=5)```


Ant got this error:


```Cannot resolve keyword 'review_date' into field. Choices are: clean, comf, country_area, fclt, hotel_address, hotel_id, hotel_name, hotel_url, hotelreviews, loct, review_qty, review_score, staff, vfm, wifi```

Comment: Updated my answer - this should work better.

Comment: now i got this: ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pk'```...I'm sorry, it makes me feel bad asking for so much help

Comment: can you give more of the stack trace?  What str object is having pk getatt from it?

Comment: the errors comes from ```serializers.ModelSerializer'``` I will update the questions with the ```serializer.py```. I have fixed it by changing the ```class HotelReviewSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializers)``` to ```class HotelReviewSerializer (serializers.Serializers)```, but the problem now is that it returns an array of empty objects

Comment: the serializer problem is separate from the query problem.  Test the query in the Django shell to make sure the query works, then move on to serializing it.  This doesn't make sense on a ModelSerializer, it makes sense as a filtering condition on the queryset passed TO the serializer maybe, but serialization is outside the scope of your question about filtering a query to just hotels with more than 5 reviews in a certain range - that's just a query issue, not a serialization issue.

Comment: It seems the query works...now i will fix the serializer problem...omg thats so complicated...but thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through Hotel Reviews,  why not start with Hotels?
Try this
Hotels.objects.filter(review_qty__lte=5).hotel_reviews_set.filter(review_date__range=('2018-01-01', '2019-12-12'))

Comment: thats do the same i have...get the hotels with more than 5 reviews and get all the reviews from 2018/2019 but dont filter the hotels with more than 5 reviews in 2019